# Nextjs admin dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I want to make an admin dashboard for an ecommerce website. I want to display stuff like statistics and orders that have been made but i also want to enable the admin user to CRUD products, discounts etc. since the website is a fullstack nextjs app and i use prisma for the backend, is there something that automatically generates an admin dashboard based on the prisma models for example? Coming from Django, i  really like how it comes with a admin dashboaard out of the box so looking for something similar.